# Using cut delim with zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm cleaning up files that were downloaded with query caching strings. The files look like:

```
frontend-legacy.min.css?ver=3.2.4.css
```

Run I run this code in a Bash shell, it works fine and removes the "?ver=3.2.4.css" from the file.

```
for i in `find ./build $1 -type f -name "*\?*"`; do mv -f $i `echo $i | cut -d? -f1`; done
```

Run I run it in a ZSH shell "cut -d?" is throwing an error. Why is the delimiter character not working in ZSH?

Comment: Try `cut -d'?' -f1` with single quotes to keep the shell from thinking the ? is special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` is a glob character. `-d?` tries to expand to all file names in the working directory, which start with `-d` and have one more letter. If there is no such file, what happens depends on how you have configured your zsh: It may silently pass the `-d?` string to the application, or it may output an error message.

This applies to all wildcard characters (`*` and `[` for instance). If you want to use them literally, you need to quote or escape them. For instance, writing `-d\?` would work.